# Python delimiters - from grib to json through csv - Copernicus API

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, tabulator

After downloading data from the Copernicus API I'm receiving a .grib file which after conversion to .csv returns with these set :

```
Latitude, Longitude, Value
   52.250   -7.250 2.7973606873e+02
   52.250   -7.000 2.7972239685e+02
Latitude, Longitude, Value
   52.250   -7.250 2.8023333740e+02
   52.250   -7.000 2.8015911865e+02
Latitude, Longitude, Value
   52.250   -7.250 2.8040211487e+02
   52.250   -7.000 2.8019508362e+02
Latitude, Longitude, Value
   52.250   -7.250 2.8189350891e+02
   52.250   -7.000 2.8173139954e+02
Latitude, Longitude, Value
   52.250   -7.250 2.8369824219e+02
   52.250   -7.000 2.8324902344e+02
Latitude, Longitude, Value
   52.250   -7.250 2.8529223633e+02
   52.250   -7.000 2.8480590820e+02
Latitude, Longitude, Value
   52.250   -7.250 2.8735998535e+02
   52.250   -7.000 2.8681311035e+02
```

What I want next is to json dictionary with Latitude, Longitude and Value.

Here's what I did until now :

```
import csv, json

csvPath = "sample_area.csv"
editedCsv = "sample_edited.csv"
jsonPath = "formatted.json"

with open(csvPath, 'r') as f_in, open(editedCsv, 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(next(f_in))
    [f_out.write(','.join(line.split()) + '\n') for line in f_in]

data = {}

with open(csvPath) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        Latitude = csvRow["Latitude"]
        data[Latitude] = csvRow

print(data)

with open(jsonPath, "w") as jsonFile:
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print('\n', editedCsv.lower(), "has been edited and", jsonPath, "has been created", '\n')
```

The problem is that after changing delimiter between Latitude, Longitude and Value I get double comma ',,' :

```
Latitude, Longitude, Value
52.250,-7.250,2.7973606873e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.7972239685e+02
Latitude,,Longitude,,Value
52.250,-7.250,2.8023333740e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8015911865e+02
Latitude,,Longitude,,Value
52.250,-7.250,2.8040211487e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8019508362e+02
Latitude,,Longitude,,Value
52.250,-7.250,2.8189350891e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8173139954e+02
Latitude,,Longitude,,Value
52.250,-7.250,2.8369824219e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8324902344e+02
Latitude,,Longitude,,Value
52.250,-7.250,2.8529223633e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8480590820e+02
Latitude,,Longitude,,Value
52.250,-7.250,2.8735998535e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8681311035e+02
```

And (I think) because of that my json looks like this :

```
{
    "   52.250   -7.250 2.7973606873e+02": {
        "Latitude": "   52.250   -7.250 2.7973606873e+02",
        " Longitude": null,
        " Value": null
    },
    "   52.250   -7.000 2.7972239685e+02": {
        "Latitude": "   52.250   -7.000 2.7972239685e+02",
        " Longitude": null,
        " Value": null
    },
    "Latitude": {
        "Latitude": "Latitude",
        " Longitude": " Longitude",
        " Value": " Value"
    },
    "   52.250   -7.250 2.8023333740e+02": {
        "Latitude": "   52.250   -7.250 2.8023333740e+02",
        " Longitude": null,
        " Value": null
    },
    "   52.250   -7.000 2.8015911865e+02": {
        "Latitude": "   52.250   -7.000 2.8015911865e+02",
        " Longitude": null,
        " Value": null
    },
    "   52.250   -7.250 2.8040211487e+02": {
        "Latitude": "   52.250   -7.250 2.8040211487e+02",
        " Longitude": null,
        " Value": null
    },
```

How to change this code to receive correct json file ?

What I want to achieve eventually is a simple dictionary which looks something like this :

```
Latitude, Longitude, Value
52.250,-7.250,2.7973606873e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.7972239685e+02
52.250,-7.250,2.8023333740e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8015911865e+02
52.250,-7.250,2.8040211487e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8019508362e+02
52.250,-7.250,2.8189350891e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8173139954e+02
52.250,-7.250,2.8369824219e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8324902344e+02
52.250,-7.250,2.8529223633e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8480590820e+02
52.250,-7.250,2.8735998535e+02
52.250,-7.000,2.8681311035e+02
```

Comment: "What I want to achieve eventually is a simple dictionary which looks something like this" it's not a dictionary it's a csv file. you want output as json or csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

with open('data.csv') as fp, open('data.json', 'w') as fw:
    columns = fp.readline().strip().split(',')
    data = [line.strip().split() for line in fp if ',' not in line]
    res = [dict(zip(columns, x)) for x in data]
    json.dump(res, fw)
```

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.250",
    "Value": "2.7973606873e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.000",
    "Value": "2.7972239685e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.250",
    "Value": "2.8023333740e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.000",
    "Value": "2.8015911865e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.250",
    "Value": "2.8040211487e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.000",
    "Value": "2.8019508362e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.250",
    "Value": "2.8189350891e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.000",
    "Value": "2.8173139954e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.250",
    "Value": "2.8369824219e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.000",
    "Value": "2.8324902344e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.250",
    "Value": "2.8529223633e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.000",
    "Value": "2.8480590820e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.250",
    "Value": "2.8735998535e+02"
  },
  {
    "Latitude": "52.250",
    "Longitude": "-7.000",
    "Value": "2.8681311035e+02"
  }
]
```

**Another solution:**

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

with open('data.csv') as fp, open('data.json', 'w') as fw:
    columns = fp.readline().strip().split(',')
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for line in fp:
        if ',' not in line:
            x, y, z = line.strip().split()
            res[columns[0]].append(x)
            res[columns[1]].append(y)
            res[columns[2]].append(z)
print(dict(res))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Latitude': ['52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250', '52.250'], ' Longitude': ['-7.250', '-7.000', '-7.250', '-7.000', '-7.250', '-7.000', '-7.250', '-7.000', '-7.250', '-7.000', '-7.250', '-7.000', '-7.250', '-7.000'], ' Value': ['2.7973606873e+02', '2.7972239685e+02', '2.8023333740e+02', '2.8015911865e+02', '2.8040211487e+02', '2.8019508362e+02', '2.8189350891e+02', '2.8173139954e+02', '2.8369824219e+02', '2.8324902344e+02', '2.8529223633e+02', '2.8480590820e+02', '2.8735998535e+02', '2.8681311035e+02']}
```

Comment: Thank you @komatiraju032 this indeed solves the comma issue. Still - what I need to achieve instead of list of dictionaries is one dictionary with Latitude, Longitude and Value columns. Sorry if I did not explain it comprehensively enough earlier.

Comment: @Geophysicist can you post the expected output

Comment: Sure @komatiraju032. I did already update the main thread.

Comment: it's not a dictionary can you clarify this?

Comment: You're right - I actually think I'm better off with a list of dictionaries. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @Geophysicist I have updated my post with another method check once